# Cover a convex set with the union of ellipsoids?

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis, computational-geometry, ellipsoids

> Find a set of ellipsoids $\{\mathcal E_k\}_{k=1}^N$ such that their union contains a convex set $\mathcal P$, i.e., $$\mathcal P\subseteq\bigcup_{k=1}^N\mathcal E_k$$

---

I am wondering (because Google is not helping) if there are algorithms out there that can solve (variations of) this problem. From what I understand, this is an NP-hard problem. However, I do not know what the common name for it is - and am not able to find any papers that tackle algorithms/heuristics to solve the problem. Are there any?

**Clarification**: assume that there are constraints on the size of $\mathcal E_k$. For example, they are generated by a black box method that generates ellipsoids of contant volume, but random shape (rotation, principal axes).

Comment: I suppose you refer to bounded convex sets. If a convex set was unbounded, I think it could not be covered by a finite union of ellipsoids. Moreover, if a convex set is bounded, it can be covered by just one ellipsoid, indeed since the convex set is bounded, it is contained in a ball (sphere) and any ellipsoid that contains the ball, contains the convex set too.

Comment: Thanks @Angelo for pointing that out. I added a clarifications that the ellipsoids cannot be arbitrarily large.

Comment: I think this is related to the "covering problem," although I think usually the covering problem just looks at any neighborhood (and doesn't restrict to ellipsoids). I think a common assumption is for the underlying set to be compact. You might also want to check out the functional version of this -- there is plenty of literature for finding upper and lower bounds on the $\epsilon$-entropy of "bounded variation functions"